# What's the difference between Principle of bivalence and law of excluded middle?

Tags: propositional-calculus

My understanding is excluded middle stay in the syntactic level $P\,\vee \,\neg P$ while Principle of bivalence interpret $P$ and $\neg P$ to some certain meaning.
But I'm not sure about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's basically right. Excluded middle is a formula, and hence essentially a syntactic thing, whereas the principle of bivalence is a property of models.

Probably the easiest way to understand this is via boolean valued models. Let $\mathbb{B}$ be a [boolean algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_%28structure%29). Then a *boolean valued model* is a function $f$ from proposition variables to $\mathbb{B}$. (That is, if $P_1,P_2,\ldots$ are proposition variables, then $f(P_1), f(P_2),\ldots$ are elements of $\mathbb{B}$.) We can extend $f$ to every formula by setting $f(\phi \wedge \psi) = f(\phi) \wedge f(\psi)$ and similarly for the other logical symbols.

We can call the elements of $\mathbb{B}$ "truth values" and say that $1 \in \mathbb{B}$ is "true". Boolean valued models then have the nice property that whenever $\phi$ is a theorem of propositional calculus, $f(\phi) = 1$. That is, every theorem of the propositional calculus is "true" in every boolean valued model. We call this *soundness*.

Excluded middle is the formula $P \vee \neg P$ of the propositional calculus. It is an axiom of the propositional calculus and as such has to hold in *every* boolean valued model by soundness. (Although there are more general models where excluded middle does not always hold).

The most basic (non trivial) boolean algebra has only two elements, $0$ and $1$. This is sometimes referred to as $2$. Boolean valued models built using this two element boolean algebra have only two truth values, and hence can be referred to as *bivalent*. However, there are many other boolean algebras with more than two elements. These give non bivalent models where excluded middle holds.